# Are there any advantages to different programming paradigms specifically releated to game programming?

Tags: paradigms

I have been researching three different programming paradigms namely procedural, object oriented and functional. So far I have been able to find a lot of good information regarding general differences and advantages/disadvantages like readability, reusability, difference in learning curve, program size, etc.  I am now looking for differences more related to game programming, but I am struggling to find good examples. Does anyone know of specific issues when programming games that these paradigms handle differently, that I could look into? This could include things like handling i/o, rendering and programming AI, but other things releated to game programming would also be apperciated.

Comment: this is not really a question for SO, try posting it here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about that. I will try that site. Thanks.